# Adding text on video frame of dash stream

Tags: javascript, video-streaming, html5-video, mpeg-dash

I had implemented the both client side and server side for dash video streaming everything is working well
(I used dash.all.min.js from the **Github** for client side)

**I want to add text on video frames before they display on html video player is it possible to do it
(client side)**

Comment: Provide some link to your code.

Answer (score 0):

To add text to a DASH video you have several options, depending on what you mean by client side:

- Add a text track to the DASH video. This is usually done server side and the client then uses this info to display it client side. You can see more info here and an example with a commonly used tool: https://www.bento4.com/developers/dash/subtitles/
- Embed the text in the frames themselves - this is typically quite processor intensive so it not something you would want to do on the client side. If you do want to do this then FFMPEG is probably a good place to start, server side anyway.
- Add a text overlay on the client itself - e.g. a text 'div' or element on a browser App, or a TextView on Android etc. You can take timing events from the video to trigger changing the text. This is probably the simplest if it meets your need and avoid any extra video processing.

Comment: Everything was good if I implemented it on client side .how can I achieve security. I need the text must and should display